# Centralized logging in elasticsearch - avoiding mapping explosion

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a microservices-based system. We collect all the logs from all services in a central place, that being Elasticsearch. We use dynamic mapping. Logs can be written by our code or by the underlying framework that we use. We hit the index mapping explosion problem. I've read the article https://www.elastic.co/blog/3-ways-to-prevent-mapping-explosion-in-elasticsearch, but would like to know what are the best practices to tackle the issue of having too many indexed fields.

Acceptance criteria:

1. Don't be too strict by controlling explicitly every indexed field, to avoid bureaucracy when adding new field. When the mapping of an existing field is changed, this requires re-indexing.
2. Facilitate system monitoring. We might not know during development time what fields the production support team will be searching by when monitoring the system.
3. Every service might use its own domain language, having different names for same data. Creating a common logging language is not an option.

I'm inclined to explicitly define an complex object field with dynamic mapping enabled, something like "tags", that would contain fields that will be automatically indexed. For everything else, indexing will be disabled.

Could you please share your way of organizing centralized logging in elasticsearch?

Comment: I've seen this problem solved in several ways in production systems, but honestly, the best practice will challenge your 3rd acceptance criteria. It could be helpful to clarify (1) why you're writing into the same index documents that have such different mappings, (2) what are the monitoring use cases that require every single field to be searchable

Comment: I'm planning to introduce an index per service. For now, I'd like to have something cheap  that allows me to see the logs from different services in one place. Answering the second question regarding the fields that will be used during the searching process - I don't know exactly what might be needed for monitoring. It is kind of data discovery.

Comment: "I'd like to have something cheap that allows me to see the logs from different services in one place" <- you can always span queries over multiple indices. I would then recommend to (1) have dedicated indices per service, (2) invest on establishing a minimum set of common fields (e.g., host, log_level, message, ...) with the same name (you can have ingestion pipelines dedicated for this job), (3) revision regularly whether anyone is searching/aggregating over any given fields, so that you can optimise the mapping